# Change div content and url on single click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, attr

I am very new to jquery.

I just need to update div content and link url on single click.

here I am working on this code.

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">$14.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$15.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$16.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$20.50</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I need to update price div based on above link click.

```
    <div class="price">$0.00</div>

    <a class="buy" href="">Pay Now</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: So what did you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.class` selector and `.attr()` to change the `href`.

```
$('ul > li').click(function(){
   $('.price').html($(this).text());
   $('.buy').attr('href', 'http://google.com');
});
```

```js
$('ul > li').click(function(){
   $('.price').html($(this).text());
   $('.buy').attr('href', 'http://google.com');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">$14.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$15.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$16.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$20.50</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="price">$0.00</div>

<a class="buy" href="">Pay Now</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like"

```js
$(".price").on('click', function(){
    var clickedPrice = $(this).data('price');
    $('#result_price').html("$" + clickedPrice);
  });
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="price"><a href="#" data-price="9">$9</a></li>
  <li class="price"><a href="#" data-price="5">$5</a></li>
  <li class="price"><a href="#" data-price="3">$3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="result_price">$0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update **price** div based on **`ul > li > a`** click. Try below code

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul > li > a', function(){
    $('.price').text($(this).text());
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'ul > li > a', function(){
    $('.price').text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">$14.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$15.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$16.50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$20.50</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="price">$0.00</div>
<a class="buy" href="">Pay Now</a>
```

Thank you.